# Python to CSV: transposing and appending values to list of lists

Tags: python, list, csv

This is probably basic, but my jetlagged brain refuses to find a solution.

I have the following lists (or list of lists):

```
#"variables" names
name=['a', 'b', 'c']
#variables values
value=[[0,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
#id number of each observation
id=[100,134,26]
```

I want to write the output to a CSV file, so that it looks like this:

```
a, b, c, id
0, 1, 1, 100
0, 0, 0, 134
1, 1, 1, 26
```

I can write any of the individual list (or list of lists) into a CSV file no problem. But how do I transpose the id list and append it to the variables values? Stacking the names on top would be a great bonus. I could always create two CSV file, but prefer not to, as the probability of error in data manipulation increases exponentially. 
This is my CSV writing bit of code (pretty standard):

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
     wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',')
     wtr.writerows(full_data)
#full_data would be the cleaned data to write into CSV file
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to write it as a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this without pandas.

```
import csv

fulldata = [name + ['id']] + [val + [id[i]]  for i, val in enumerate(value)]  

with open('mycsv.csv','w') as f:
    mywriter = csv.writer(f)
    mywriter.writerows(fulldata)
```

Will give you:

```
a,b,c,id                                                                                                        
0,1,1,100                                                                                                       
0,0,0,134                                                                                                       
1,1,1,26
```

Comment: Ah, indexing, of course. Thanks, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in value], columns=name)
df['id'] = id
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the other answer simply because I don't have pandas installed on this machine. But logically, it seems like it should work; I'll explore later.